# Assessing spatial autocorrelation in structural equation models

Tags: autocorrelation, spatial, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I have a SEM built with lavaan and I would like to assess spatial autocorrelation. I found this code written by Jarrett Byrnes that does exactly that:

http://www.imachordata.com/space-and-sems-2/

However in this page there is warning that as of 2016/10/1 lavaan is not producing correct errors. I browsed lavaan's development page and it seems the bug has not been fixed. Jarrett Byrnes recommends that users calculate the errors by hand.

Does anyone know of an alternative way of assessing spatial autocorrelation? Alternatively, how can I calculate the errors by hand?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a bug, according to the lavaan github page.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible workaround that might work for some datasets:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lavaan/ftvD1Nxb4Iw